# Yotpo reviews and galleries not loading on page change

Tags: reactjs

We have a set of Yotpo embeds that load a review section and an image gallery. On initial page load, the widget works fine, however when you navigate to another page the embed doesn't show on the page because it's loaded asynchronously.

Yotpo support suggests using

```
var api = new Yotpo.API(yotpo);
api.refreshWidgets();
```

When must be added to callback functions when new content is loaded. This however didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

In the React component, I simply added the undocumented **initWidgets()** to the **ComponentDidUpdate()** lifecycle method and it is now working like expected.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (typeof window.yotpo !== "undefined") {
    window.yotpo.initWidgets();
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone who runs into the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried this using hooks?

```useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window.yotpo !== "undefined") {
      window.yotpo.initWidgets();
    }
  }, [some.prop]);```

It seems to work with `refreshWidgets()` however not with the `init` method